# Is there a way in azure dataflow to unpivot by multiple categories?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following table with these columns and more rows of course:

| User | A1 | A2 | B1 | B2 | C1 | C2 | D1 | D2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 | value7 | value8 | value9 |

I need to transform it so it can look like this:

| User | Number | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 1 | A | value2 |
| User1 | 2 | A | value3 |
| User1 | 1 | B | value4 |
| User1 | 2 | B | value5 |
| User1 | 1 | C | value6 |
| User1 | 2 | C | Value7 |
| User1 | 1 | D | Value8 |
| User1 | 2 | D | Value9 |

What is the best way to achieve this transformation?

Comment: You could create multiple Unpivots, one for each category, then use a Union to  aggregate them together before the Sink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an Unpivot transformation and then use DerivedColumn transformation to generate type and number column.

Step:

1.Setting of Unpivot transformation:
[image]

[image]

[image]

2.Setting of DerivedColumn transformation:

[image]

Data preview of DerivedColumn transformation:
[image]

Finally, use Select transformation to delete Type_Number column is OK.